# How to create database for React app and schedule scrapers

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, web-scraping

I have a question regarding one of my React apps that I recently developed.
It's basically a landing page, which is using React frontend and Node+Express backend and its scraping data from various pages (scrapers are developed in Python).

Right now, the React app itself is hosted in Heroku and the execution of scrapers is working, but not ideally.

What I would like to do is to set up a proper flow

- create a database
- schedule the scrapers
- collect the data in the database
- request data from the database in the React app, when needed

I've read about different possibilities such as Firebase, also different AWS options like EC2, Lambda, S3 etc. I'm a bit lost in the midst of all this, so maybe you can help out and give me some suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your problem, then the scraping itself does not have to be associated with your landing page/React application. Let's walk through a potential solution.

**SQL Database**

You can use anything SQL database here, really. Create a table with relevant columns for each source that you will scrape. I personally like RDS Postgres within AWS. Scraping Yahoo Finance? Well, have a table called "yahoo" and columns such as "ticker", "open", "close", "date", etc.

**Schedule the scrapers**

I assume you already taken care of the actual scraping/extracting information from the source with Python. You can use **cronjob** or **schedule** [package](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) to schedule the scrapers to run hourly/daily/weekly/etc. Connect your scrapers to the SQL database in order to access it and store the data in whichever way you need. The scrapers can live in EC2 in AWS. You would need to do some setup for the instance. You can also connect scrapers to an application such as Sentry to easily monitor the progress and errors of scraping.

**React App**

Connect the database to the Node backend. Use a simple API call to your backend to access the data and use it. You can use sequelize ORM to access the Postgres database.

To conclude, I believe the idea is relatively straightforward, you just need to select the tools (I gave some suggestions) and start implementing them!

Comment: Hi Airis! Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I find it very helpful, trying to follow it now. I createad an EC2 instance, RDS for Mysql. What I don't understand fully right now is, how to connect EC2 (where my Python scripts are) to RDS? Maybe you can explain it a bit more.

Comment: You can use a library such as Peewee that can handle the connections to your RDS! You can check it out here: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/installation.html